# Protractor Automation: Selection of element

Tags: selenium, protractor

I'm trying to automate selection of some products...[Here's a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eI3U5.png)

The user clicks on the top row of 'base' colours and then selects the desired colour from the resulting pallet beneath.

I am able to select a base colour without issue.

```
element(by.xpath('html/body/main-app/kf-sidebar-app/div[1]/app-container/div/dashboard/div/div/visualise/open-interface/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/digitalbridge-category-list/div/digitalbridge-category-view[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]')).click();
```

...selecting the desired colour is altogether much more maddening!!! The closest I've got has resulted in a "Element not visible" message....tried adding in 'waits' but no difference.

This code..

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
 var paintSelected = element(by.xpath('.//div[@id="2386"]'));
 browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(paintSelected), 7000);
 paintSelected.click();
```

..produces line-after-line of..

```
[11:27:22] W/element - more than one element found for locator By(xpath, .//div[@id="2386"]) - the first result will be used
```

This keeps running until the 7000ms timeout is reached. I've tried using 'first' but it's not 'recognised'....also tried [0] but again, not recognised.

Here's the line from Console...

```
<div _ngcontent-c63="" class="item circle" id="2386" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://shortbite.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com:443/category/raw/941027c0-f6e6-434c-9ab9-66f9918c33e6.png?Signature=Zbffcvf73Nv9g2v9G3SmcYn6h24%3D&amp;Expires=1510141234&amp;AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIUUATNKB37DELIXQ&quot;);"> </div>
```

Please try and save my sanity! Thanks
David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting your selector into the console i.e ***$x(".//div[@id='2386']")***.
Just to see if you really have two elements with the same Id

Also do a find elements and debug the collection of elements.

One thing I have done with my extended framework is implemented a highlight element functionality.

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = Driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].setAttribute(arguments[1], arguments[2])", ReferenceElement, "style",
            "border: 2px solid red; border-style: dashed;");
```

Comment: Good one! Just the one id2386!

Comment: Does the click event work? And try browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(paintSelected), 7000)

Comment: Click event works when running manually. Tried the 'ToBeClickable' change but just got the rolling 'more than one element' message until timeout.

Comment: One thing..probably not relevant: The user can click on the colour and then click on the image to which the colour is to be applied OR drag-and-drop. The mouse pointer changes to a 'hand' when over the colours but click will select still.

Answer (score 0):

if you have id you can check all elements available with that id in chrome or firefox console like that:

```
$$('#2386')
```

$$ will return all, one $ will return the first one.

because if you have more than 1 element with the same locator, protractor will get the first one.

If there is no way to give you elements different locators you can get it by index.

for example in you code first loacte all elements and assign it to varible:

```
var allColors = $$('#2386'); // same as element.all(by.id('2386'))
```

or get them by index

```
var firstColor = $$('#2386').get(0); // or $$('#2386').first();
var secondColor = $$('#2386').get(1); // or $$('#2386').first();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use firepath and find out the absolute xpath .
Then add some wait and try to click on the element using absolute xpath

Comment: I know this is not a recommended method. But you could try and check whether it works.Please let me know if it doesn't work